# Java persistence in database

Tags: java, persistence

What is the simplest way to use database persistence in Java?  I know, many frameworks exists around the Internet, but it could be fun to learn how to develop a persistence layer by myself and its design patterns.  Where to start?  Books, websites, how-tos, code-examples, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with Sun's Java Persistence API (JPA).  Here's a [good starter article](http://web.archive.org/web/20091028153606/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/jpa/).

Answer (score 4):

Start by looking at features and source code of pre-existing ones. Here are a couple (just to name a few in alphabetical order)

- [DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/): A very simple wrapper for JDBC. Maybe start looking here for ideas!
- [EBean](http://www.avaje.org/): Similar to JPA itself
- [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/): The de-facto standard that heavily influenced Java's JPA specifications
- [iciql](http://iciql.com/): A friendly fork of JaQu
- [JaQu](http://www.h2database.com/html/jaqu.html): H2's own domain specific language for querying databases
- [JDBI](http://jdbi.codehaus.org): Exposes relational database access in idiommatic Java
- [JDO](http://db.apache.org/jdo/): Apache Java Data Objects
- [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org): Modelling SQL as a domain specific language directly in Java
- [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/): "the world's most popular SQL mapping framework." [sic] (formerly iBatis)
- [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/): A SQL-like fluent API with many different backends (not just SQL)
- [Quaere](http://quaere.codehaus.org/): Similar to QueryDSL

And soon, you can edit this answer and add your own framework!

Answer (score 3):

> it could be fun to learn how to develop a persistence layer by myself

Noooo! Don't be silly.

Use [JDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Data_Objects) or [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API). The first one is a generic object persistence API, the other one is aimed at RDBMS-es only.

They have various implementations, e.g. for JPA there is EclipseLink (formerly Oracle TopLink), which is also the reference implementation for JPA 2, and Hibernate, which is also very popular.

You really, really don't want to make your own. If you want to work in this area, then contribute to one of the existing projects instead.

Answer (score 3):

Another library that's useful is [jDBI](http://jdbi.org/). It takes advantage of generics to have nice binding + mapping capabilities while still being fairly close to JDBC. [iBATIS](http://ibatis.apache.org/) is supposed to have similar characteristics though not so lightweight, and it's been around for much longer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplist way is just to use [jdbc](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/database/).
Java has a nice tutorial [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

As far as abstraction layers go.  [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/), in my experience, is pretty standard, and worth learning.  Programming your own can be a fun exercise, but I can't think of a good reason not to use hibernate.

Comment: I've found that using an SQL mapper like iBatis on top of JDBC is much, much easier than using raw JDBC.  This should be true of ORMs like Hibernate and JPA too.  In all these approaches the framework takes care of many of the details for you.  These include optimizations like connection pooling and prevention of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: For what it's worth, I really like jDBI (http://jdbi.org/); it handles all the nasty parts of JDBC, allows data binding if you want, but tries to stay out of the way otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

At the lowest level you'll need to talk to a database so you'll be using [JDBC](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/database/). Since you're designed your own framework you're own your own after that. Have a look an [JPA](http://java.sun.com/javaee/overview/faq/persistence.jsp) and [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) to get some ideas and then experiment away.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous responses - check the DAO (Data Access Object) pattern - it reflects how the code for data access should be organized.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926165/) to be particularly useful. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131401572) is a good one too.

Having created one myself I agree - it is a lot of fun, and a lot of work too. It all depends on your objectives.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a learning practice then try to get a copy of Craig Larman's **[Applying UML and Patterns.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137488807)**

[image]
<sub>(source: [codivation.com](http://graysmatter.codivation.com/content/binary/applyingumlandpatterns.jpg))</sub>

There Larman presents a chapter on lightweight database persistence mapper design. Unlike Hibernate, which is based on an unobtrusive persistence model, he presents an obtrusive framework in which domain objects has to be extended from a PersistentObject. We also have to write mapper classes for each persistent domain class. Its some sort of ActiveRecord pattern without any codegeneration concept.

Answer (score 0):

This [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) (*Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*) seems very good at first sight.  I have look into it, and design patterns for developing a persistence engine are very comprehensive.  It tells why, when and how to use them.